# How to do basic auth to acces external url and advoid System.HttpResponse[Status=Forbidden, StatusCode=403]

Tags: apex, rest-api, callout, httprequest, oauth

I have a basic auth which I have working with Postman but when I do this with apex I get an Forbidden error. The variables userKeyVal and  userSecretVal are filled correctly, my url is correct and I granted acces trough remote site setings. What am I missing.

Postman

```
    **Key**             **Value**      
    Content-Type    application/json
    Authorization   Basic AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA==

Update(not needed):
    client_id       123456789  
    client_secret   BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
```

Apex

```
  @TestVisible static Boolean doCallout = true;
    @future(callout=true)
    //Get Stock
    public static void  getStock() {
        if(doCallout) {
        fetchConfiguration();   
            Http http = new Http();
            HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
            request.setEndpoint(UrlVal +'stock/?');
            request.setMethod('GET');
            request.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json'); 

            Blob headerValue = Blob.valueOf(userKeyVal + ':' + userSecretVal);
            String authorizationHeader = 'BASIC ' +EncodingUtil.base64Encode(headerValue);
            request.setHeader('Authorization', authorizationHeader);

            HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
            if (response.getStatusCode() == 200) {
            System.debug('response: ' + response);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sometimes postman is adding some extra headers, make sure that you have them all. Is it also working with curl? Extra tip (in case you don't know about it), you could use "Named Credentials", it is an easier way to authenticate with webservices without having to store users and passwords elsewhere.

Comment: I see that in Apex you have sent "Basic" in all caps but in the excerpt from postman it is only capital B. Could you check?

Comment: This also seems to be OAuth password and username because I don't see the client id and secret being set in Apex. With that being said, I would go with "named credentials" if this is a new implementation.

Comment: @JefersonChaves I checked the Basic. In this case are not the values userKeyVal + ':' + userSecretVal the client_id and client_secret?. In postname these seem to be base64 or do I need to set these separately?

Comment: As Jeferson mentioned, you might need also `request.setHeader('client_id', '123456789');`and `request.setHeader('client_secret', 'BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB');`

Comment: @SergioAlcocer How would i generate 123456789 and BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB are these also EncodingUtil.base64Encode of the username and password?

Comment: @Thomas, usually those are given by the provider of the webservice so that they can identify the "Application" that is calling them (one thing is the credentials (Authorization) and a different thing is the application). They very rarely are in base64, they are just a bunch of random numbers and numbers and letters.
Similar to Salesforce, you have the username and password (Authorization), but you could have a client id and secret to be able to see in the login history from which App the login happened.

Comment: @SergioAlcocer I indeed changed Basic to Basic. What is do not understand is in Postman I only fill in the Username and Pasword for the Basic Auth I do not fill in the client_id or client_secret so why would I need to fill these in apex?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107378/discussion-between-sergio-alcocer-and-thomas).

Comment: @Thomas: not really used this method before (used old plain basic authentication that was similar). To be really transparent, I fell that postman is performing some background work for you that named credentials could perform, otherwise you will have to set those things through code.

Comment: It needs to be `Authorization: Basic ...`, the value of the header is case-sensitive. Some servers incorrectly treat value as case-insensitive and there might be another root cause to this but Basic vs BASIC is probably it. Assuming it's a case issue, [Named Credential](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts_named_credentials.htm) would have saved you from that and you wouldn't have had to add the site to Remote Settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For someone how bumps into this. Im my case the code was working properly. The Ip addresses of Salesforce needed to be whitelisted on the other end.